# Run command to optimize images after they get uploaded to WordPress

Tags: images, uploads, optimization

I been playing with jpegoptim on a ubuntu test server and like the result of its optimization, its there a way to run the optimization command to the new images uploaded through WordPress?

Im aware of all the plugins that do such thing but I really don't like how bloated they are for such simple task.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: started to write an answer, but it is really heavily OS and OS shell script related and therefor maybe here is not the best place. Once you have a script that can run your command when files are added or changed, wordpress specific nuances (not sure there are any right now) can be added here

Comment: Great @MarkKaplun. This is WordPress professionals exchange. You can share anything you find attractive and that can be helpful for some other WordPress developer.

Comment: @prosti, while the question is on topic, in can be reduced to something which might get better answers on SE or super user. A good answer will require expertise in OS scheduling and shell scripting, something that many here can probably do, but probably none are experts in that

Comment: @MarkKaplun, fully agree with you. There are people who know to appreciate the quality posts and little extra details won't hurt. Whatever you decide...

Comment: Or, maybe write a php wrapper for calling the binary, and call that wrapper with the add_attachment hook. Similar idea:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12339/getting-path-to-uploaded-attachment-image-after-upload

Comment: I think @CC is into something, I modified the code on the  he referred to but it only optimizes the uploaded image, how can I make it run on each of the wordpress images sizes?

Comment: @Brooke, do you still need the answer in here?

Comment: @prosti I sure do =(

Comment: @MarkKaplun started to write the answer as you noted. As I have a great respect, we will wait a bit more until he replies. After that, I would probably add some cherries on the top.

Comment: BTW @Brooke, I wish you a great time here in the WordPress SO.

Comment: @prosti thanks, I have tried quite a few things,**incron**( is not recursive)**watcher.py** works but it fires the optimization multiple times it detects each image size that is created by wordpress and it created issues when uploading multiple images at the same time,**add_attachment** works only on the main image and does not optimize the different images sizes generated also tried **gulp-image** but couldn't get the watch function to work and for what I understand it re-optimizes all the images each time it runs making the images look really bad, some images got as far of to 0kb size.

Comment: so far, the best approach I came up with is to run a cron job every 5 minutes that searches for images created in the past 5 minutes and if it finds them it optimize them, the cron runs Monday through Friday from 8am to 5pm, unless @MarkKaplun has a better option?